# textbox does not accept a value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code a have written for an asp.net website, v2005

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEFName = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
phFname.Controls.Add(txtEFName);
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
```

This code when executed, always shows the value of the textbox "" even if I enter some string.

Please help.

Comment: When / where are you trying to read back the value?  And when / where is the code that adds the TextBox executed?

Comment: Where do you create this textbox? And where are you retrieving the value of the dynamically created textbox?

Comment: I'm flipping the value of the placeholder from a label to textbox on a click of button and then reading the value of the textbox by the click of the same button

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic controls need to be re-created each time the page loads. So you need to have that code execute during the Page_Init event. **Note**: You need to assign a unique ID for this control that stays the same each time the page loads.

Why all this?

Because the control is not contained in the markup (the .aspx file), you need to add it again every time the page loads. So how does it retain its value? The value will be stored in the ViewState, and as long as the control has the same ID it will be repopulated with the correct value.

To keep things running smoothly, let's put the code for adding the control in a separate function.

```
Private void AddMyControl()
{
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEFName = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
   txtEFName.ID = something unique;
   phFname.Controls.Add(txtEFName);
}
```

So we can call it from both the click handler and the Page_Init handler, but we only need to call it in the Page_Init if we have already clicked. So let's store that as a flag inside a Session variable (you can also store it in the ViewState if you like, but let's keep it that way for now). So our click handler will now look something like this:

```
void ButtonSomething_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
   AddMyControl();
   Session["MyControlFlag"] == true;
}
```

Now we need our Page_Init handler:

```
Public void Page_Init(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Session["MyControlFlag"]!=null && (bool)Session["MyControlFlag"])
      AddMyControl();
}
```

Comment: It should be assigned an ID as well.

Comment: I need to execute this code on the click of a button. After assigning an id also its not working.

Comment: @Sarfaraz - You'll need to populate it again in the Page_Init with the same Id. One way of doing it is to make a boolean flag that you store in a session or a hidden field. When you click the button you flip that flag to true, and in the Page_Init event you check for that flag and if true add the control again. Makes sense?

Comment: But populating it again will set it again to "". Isn't it?

Comment: @Sarfaraz - You're not populating it again. You are adding it back to the page (because it's not contained in the aspx markup). The ViewState will then populate it with the previous value as long as it has the same ID.

Comment: I want to use the value of textbox in my code so cant declare it in another function and providing the same ID and isn't working for me. Its still not reading the value of the textbox.

Comment: @Sarfaraz - Then place the declaration as a global variable

Comment: @Sarfaraz - What do you mean doesn't work? Are you getting an error? What?

Comment: No error but the same problem. TextBox value is not changing from "". @SystemDown- is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @Sarfaraz - That's the only way of doing dynamic controls. I'm sure you're doing something wrong, though I'm not sure what. Can you post your code in a pastebin and share the link